# Language agnostic cookie encoding / decoding standards

Tags: cookies, encoding, language-agnostic, decoding, web-standards

I'm having difficulties to figure out what is the standard (or is there any?) for encoding/decoding cookie values regardless to backend platforms.

According to [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt):

> The VALUE is opaque to the user agent and may be anything the origin server chooses to send, possibly in a server-selected printable ASCII encoding.  "Opaque" implies that the content is of interest and relevance only to the origin server.  The content may, in fact, be readable by anyone that examines the Set-Cookie header.

which sounds like "server is the boss" and it decides whatever the encoding will apply. This makes it quite difficult to set a cookie from, say PHP backend and read it from Python or Java or whatever, without writing any manual encode/decode handling on both sides.

Let's say we have a value needs to be encoded. Russian `/"печенье (*} значения"/` means "cookie value" with some additional non alpha-numeric chars in it.

**Python:**

Almost every WSGI server does the same and uses Python's [SimpleCookie](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookie.html#Cookie.SimpleCookie) class that encodes to / decodes from [octal literals](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/Cookie.py#l235) even though many says that [octal literals are depreciated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Integers) in ECMA-262, strict mode. Wtf?

So, our raw cookie value becomes `"/\"\320\277\320\265\321\207\320\265\320\275\321\214\320\265 (*} \320\267\320\275\320\260\321\207\320\265\320\275\320\270\321\217\"/"`

**Node.js:**

Haven't tested at all but I'm just guessing a JavaScript backend would do it with native [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) functions that use [hexadecimal](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes#hexadecimal) escaping / unescaping?

**PHP:**

PHP applies [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to the cookie values that is similar to [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) but not exactly the same.

So the raw value becomes; `%2F%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%B5+%28%2A%7D+%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%22%2F` that is not even wrapped with double quotes.

However; if the JavaScript `value` variable has the PHP encoded value above, `decodeURIComponent(value)` gives `/"печенье+(*}+значения"/`, see "+" chars instead of spaces..

**What is the situation in Java, Ruby, Perl and .NET?** Which language is following (or closest) to the desired behaviour. Actually, is there any standard for this defined by W3?

Answer (score 4):

I think you've got things a bit mixed up here. The server's encoding does not matter to the client, and it shouldn't. That is what RFC 2109 is trying to say here.

The concept of cookies in http is similar to this in real life: Upon paying the entrance fee to a club you get an ink stamp on your wrist. This allows you to leave and reenter the club without paying again. All you have to do is show your wrist to the bouncer. In this real life example, you don't care what it looks like, it might even be invisible in normal light - all that is important is that the bouncer recognises the thing. If you were to wash it off, you'll lose the privilege of reentering the club without paying again.

In HTTP the same thing is happening. The server sets a cookie with the browser. When the browser comes back to the server (read: the next HTTP request), it shows the cookie to the server. The server recognises the cookie, and acts accordingly. Such a cookie could be something as simple as a "WasHereBefore" marker. Again, it's not important that the browser understands what it is. If you delete your cookie, the server will just act as if it has never seen you before, just like the bouncer in that club would if you washed off that ink stamp.

Today, a lot of cookies store just one important piece of information: a session identifier. Everything else is stored server-side and associated with that session identifier. The advantage of this system is that the actual data never leaves the server and as such can be trusted. Everything that is stored client-side can be tampered with and shouldn't be trusted.

**Edit:** After reading your comment and reading your question *yet again*, I think I finally understood your situation, and why you're interested in the cookie's actual encoding rather than just leaving it to your programming language: If you have two different software environments on the same server (e.g.: Perl *and* PHP), you may want to decode a cookie that was set by the other language. In the above example, PHP has to decode the Perl cookie or vice versa.

*There is no standard in how data is stored in a cookie*. The standard only says that a browser will send the cookie back *exactly as it was received*. The encoding scheme used is whatever your programming language sees fit.

Going back to the real life example, you now have two bouncers one speaking English, the other speaking Russian. The two will have to agree on one type of ink stamp. More likely than not this will involve at least one of them learning the other's language.

Since the browser behaviour is standardized, you can either imitate one languages encoding scheme in all other languages used on your server, or simply create your own standardized encoding scheme in all languages being used. You may have to use lower level routines, such as PHP's `header()` instead of higher level routines, such as `start_session()` to achieve this.

BTW: In the same manner, it is the server side programming language that decides how to store server side session data. You cannot access Perl's `CGI::Session` by using PHP's `$_SESSION` array.

Comment: +1 for the invisible ink! Though cookies can very well be used to share structured data between servers on one and the same domain.

Comment: yes, good example. i'd love to give the bounty to this, if it answered the question in **bold** part. anyways, cookies should be able to be read cross platform whatever the type of data they carry.. sad and pain in the ass.

Comment: I think I finally understood your question, and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Nice explanation and analogies. +1

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the cookie being opaque to the client, it still needs to conform to the HTTP spec. [rfc2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) specifies that all HTTP headers should be ASCII (ISO-8859-1). [rfc5987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987) extends that to support other character sets, but I don't know how widely supported it is.

Comment: ASCII is a subset (the lower half) of ISO-8859-1

Comment: @flup, you're right. If I'm understanding the rfc correctly, it actually expects ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to encode into UTF8 and wrap with base64 encoding. It's fast, ubiquitous, and will never mangle your data at either end.

You will need to ensure an explicit conversion into UTF8 even when wrapping it. Other languages & runtimes, while supporting Unicode, may not store strings as UTF8 internally... like many Windows APIs. Python 2.x, in my experience, rarely gets Unicode strings right without explicit conversion.

ENCODE: nativeString -> utfEncode() -> base64Encode()

DECODE: base64Decode() -> utfDecode() -> nativeString

Almost every language I know of, these days, supports this. You can look for a universal single-function encode, but I err on the side of caution and choose the two-step approach... especially with foreign character sets.